# AngularJS - Unable to get Resolved Value of a Factory's Method which Uses Promises in Directive's TemplateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, promise

I'm working on a very modularized project and currently I'm building an `Element Directive` which changes `templateUrl` based on user `login/logout`.

To do that, I'm trying to execute a `Factory's Function` inside `templateUrl`. That particular functions calls another method from a `JWT Factory` and returns `true` if the user is logged or `false` if not.

Then, If in my `templateUrl` I receive `true`, I pick a certain `url`, if `false` another one.

But, sadly, I receive the following error:

> `[$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string.  Received: {}`

All `$log.log()` print the correct result.

Of course, it won't render nor `page1` nor `page2`

**Directive**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', ['SessionCheckerFactory',  function (SessionCheckerFactory) {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl : function(){
          return SessionCheckerService.checkSession().then( function (res) {
            console.log(res);//true
            return res ? 'app/page1.html' : 'app/page2.html';
      });
        },
        controller       : 'MyController',
        controllerAs     : 'myCtrl',
        bindToController : true

      };
    }]);
})();
```

**SessionCheckerFactory**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('SessionCheckerFactory', function (AuthTokenFactory) {

      function checkSession() {
          return AuthTokenFactory.isAuth();
      }          

      return {
        checkSession: checkSession
      }

    });
})();
```

**AuthTokenFactory**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('AuthTokenFactory', function AuthTokenFactory(store, $cookies) {

      //Takes user's info from LocalStorage, if not empty returns a String with encoded string informations
      function getToken() {
       if (store.get(key)) {
         return store.get(key);
       }
        //Takes user's info from cookie
        var token = $cookies.get('token', {path: '/'});
        store.set(key, token);

        return token;
      }

      //If getToken is empty returns false, else true
      function isAuth() {
        return Promise.resolve(Boolean(getToken()));
      }

      return { 
              isAuth   : isAuth,
              getToken : getToken
      }
 });
})();
```

I read around that this problem is usually generated by `$http` requests, but that's not my case. I didn't find any solution to that so far.

**How can I fix this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but you should [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: What is  `getToken`?

Comment: Those IIFEs look pretty useless.

Comment: @Bergi I need IFES to check which `url` I have to load. `getToken` checks if the suser exists in `LocalStorage` and `cookies`. It works. The problem is caused by `async tasks`. I'll give a look to the link you shared. Thanks.

Comment: I don't mean the `if`s, I mean the IIFEs around your modules. Drop them and put the  `"use strict"` inside the directive/factories.

Comment: Ok, didn't get it before. Tried but It does not seem to be the problem. I read answers to the link you sent but I don't find errors in my promises. If you find some please tell me.

Comment: Not related to the problem indeed, but better code nonetheless. It should read simply `function checkSession() { return AuthTokenFactory.isAuth(); }`, `function isAuth() { return Promise.resolve(Boolean(getToken())); }` and `function templateUrl() { return SessionCheckerFactory.checkSession().then( function (res) { return res ? "app/page1.html" : "app/page2.html"; }); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue using a `link` function and `$templateRequest`

**Directive**

```
link: function (scope, element) {
      SessionCheckerService.renderTemplate().then(function (temp){
        $templateRequest(temp).then(function (requestedTemplate) {
          element.html(requestedTemplate);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
      });
    }
```

**Factory**

```
var templateConfig = './app/config/templates.config.json';

function getTemplate(){
  return $http.get(templateConfig)
    .then(function(templates) {
      return templates.data;
    });
}

function checkSession() {
  return Promise.resolve(AuthTokenFactory.isAuth());
}

function whichTemplate(template, result) {
  var myTemplate = '';
  if(result){
     myTemplate = template.logIn;
  } else {
     myTemplate = template.logOut;
  }
    if(myTemplate){
       return Promise.resolve(myTemplate);
    }

 }

//Chaining the methods and returning the correct template
function renderTemplate() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
     checkSession().then(function(isAuth){
       getTemplate().then( function(templates){
         whichTemplate(templates, isAuth).then( function (temp) {
           return resolve(temp);
         });
       });
     });
   });
 }

 return {
   renderTemplate : renderTemplate
 }
```

**Templates Config**

```
{
  "logOut" : "app/page1.html",
  "logIn"  : "app/page2.html"
}
```

I hope It'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, If in my templateUrl I receive true, I pick a certain url, if false another one.

Actually you don't. If you receive `true`, you pick one url, if some truthy value, another url, and if something falsy then you don't pick *any* url:

```
 if (res) {
     if (res === true) {
         return resolve('app/page1.html');
     } // else
         return resolve('app/page2.html');
 }
 // else return undefined;
```

You probably want

```
templateUrl : function(){
    return SessionCheckerFactory.checkSession().then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            return 'app/page1.html';
        } else {
            return 'app/page2.html';
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your solution but I get the same error. It seems like the error is generated when doing the resolve on `isAuth()`. I removed that, replacing it with the code you suggested but I get the same error.

Comment: What happens to the `templateUrl`? Are you sure there are no $http requests in your app?

Comment: On that specific piece of code I have no `$http` requests. I can share what `getToken()` does.

Comment: So where does the error come from then? What is its stack trace, where do you catch it? Maybe `MyController` tries to fetch the template from the url?

Comment: I updated the question. 1 - Error comes immediately after the checkSession`.then()`, even if it higlights `res = true` in debugging mode. 2 - I checked and the `Controller` gets called after that machinery. It may be due to that `templateUrl` goes in timeout before the return?

Comment: Your original code did go into a timeout, yes, your current one should not. However I don't see any reason to use promises in your `checkSession` code, it seems to be entirely synchronous?